# I am getting a compile time error in android studio when i build the project - error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I don't have any syntax error. but when i build the program, it shows compilation error as follows :

```
error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.               
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

This is my json array:

```
 {"students":[
             {"id":"1","firstname":"JOHN","lastname":"MATHEW","age":"25"},
             {"id":"2","firstname":"SANDY","lastname":"SINGH","age":"23"},
             {"id":"3","firstname":"MAYA","lastname":"TOMMY","age":"20"},
             {"id":"4","firstname":"AMBI","lastname":"SHIZ","age":"25"}
           ]
 }
```

Here is the code. I am using Android Studio and Volley library in it.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText firstname, lastname, age;
    Button insert, show;
    TextView result;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String insertUrl = "http://localhost/android_volleytest/insertStudent.php";
    String showUrl = "http://localhost/android_volleytest/connection.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert_btn);
        show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_btn);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                        showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray students = response.getJSONArray("students");
                            for (int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject student = students.getJSONObject(i);

                                String firstname = student.getString("firstname");
                                String lastname = student.getString("lastname");
                                String age = student.getString("age");

                                result.append(firstname + " " + lastname + " " + age + "\n");
                            }
                            result.append("======\n");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
        });

        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> parameters = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                        parameters.put("firstname", firstname.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("lastname", lastname.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("age", age.getText().toString());
                        return parameters;
                    }
                };
                requestQueue.add(request);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/fname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="@string/edit_fname" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/lname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="@string/edit_lname" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/age"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="@string/edit_age" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/insert_btn"
    android:text="@string/btn_insert"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:onClick="startRequest"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtView"
    android:background="#99EB99"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="285dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/show_btn"
    android:text="@string/btn_show"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:onClick="startRequest"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

gradle console

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\Users\shabeer\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\java\com\example\shabeer\myapplication\MainActivity.java:52: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                                                                                          ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.072 secs
```

Comment: log stack trace Please..

Comment: Information is good, too much is not good. I removed some pieces I'm pretty sure are not related to the problem.

Comment: Hi! You can take a look at my answer, just a syntax error when create a JsonObjectRequest, no need to post layout xml file

Answer (score 0):

If no body with that POST request, Use

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                showUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()...
```

instead of

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()...
```

Because the correct syntax you can find in **`..\src\main\java\com\android\volley\toolbox\JsonObjectRequest.java`** as the following:

```
public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
            Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)
```

and

```
public JsonObjectRequest(String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Listener<JSONObject> listener,
            ErrorListener errorListener)
```

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally added the volley.jar file into the libs folder of that app and also i added the code " compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'" in the graddle. when i removed the volley.jar file from the libs folder, the compilation error got resolved. But now my json array is not getting printed but it directly goes to the  "ErrorListener" and prints the error. It does not enter the "Response Listener".